# How do I take a screenshot in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screenshot utilities for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows)

I know this might sound like a stupid question. But in what ways can I take a screenshot? If I press **prt SC** nothing happens. I have an `Asus 1201n` with `Windows 7 32-bit`.

Comment: Please take care to research your questions more before asking. All but 1 of your 6 questions have been closed. If you continue asking low-quality and off-topic questions without even doing basic research such as a quick google search, your account may be suspended.

Comment: oops, sorry....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The image is saved on your clipboard. Open an application like Paint and Paste the picture.

Comment: So I don't get a place to save it like on a Mac or Linux?

Comment: No, but if you want more functionality you can use the Snipping Tool. Search for it in the start menu.

Comment: what a stupid print screen function.... thanks! :) (7 mins left until I can accept your answer.)

Comment: There's nothing stupid about it, it's just a different approach. It probably seems unfavorable for some people, but I for one never take a screencap without cropping or annotating it (to the extent that I have special software installed for it, but in a vacuum I'd rather have it go to the clipboard than get saved in a file somewhere and I have to go find it...)

Comment: @shinrai  well when I take a screenshot then I'm in a hurry, so I don't have time to open a editor and save it. And most of the time I take 3 screenshots in a short period of time, in linux on mac that's fine but in windows 7 it just doesn't work...

Comment: @Alvar - If you need to do it in Win7 in that fashion, the built in tool is pretty bad for your needs.  The snipping tool is a decent workaround, but you may be better off installing 3rd party software (SnagIt, PicPick, Jing, etc) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use prt sc : it copy the full screen shot
or
use alt + prt sc : it shot the current working window

and paste it paint or any apps